# Integrating Basecamp with JIRA

Tags: api, project-management, integration, jira, basecamp

Has anyone had any luck integrating [Basecamp](http://www.basecamphq.com/) with [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/)?

Even something as "simple" as assigning a Basecamp thread to a JIRA ticket and having changes to the ticket show up in Basecamp?

Answer (score 3):

I've just started using [Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/basecamp/jira/) (so I'm not sure how long its been going) and it offers Basecamp / Jira integration - with a free plan to get you going.  Features include syncing in either direction and event driven generation of tasks (eg Basecamp todo generating a Jira task).

Comment: Any luck with this integration?  I am looking at Zapier myself.

Comment: I tried it yesterday and I don't think it will do what we want. We have over 100 projects and I would have to create several zaps for each project. And there aren't enough triggers on the JIRA side, such as change of status.  Its a great concept though.

Answer (score 2):

Issue [JRA-23015](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-23015) on Atlassian's JIRA instance for JIRA is talking about some type of integration between Basecamp and JIRA.
I am not aware of any other effort to connect the two systems.